# Don't require props, when using component with HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with HOC and typescript. Compiler required passing value which is recieving from HOC.

Component which is using HOC:

```
function Coupon(props: WithAlertProps): JSX.Element {
 return <p>test {props.error}</p>
}
export default withAlert(Coupon);
```

HOC:

```
export interface WithAlertProps {
    error: string;
}

const withAlert = <P extends unknown>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FC<P & WithAlertProps> => (props) => {
    return (
            <Component {...props} error={"sample error"} />
    );
};

export default withAlert;
```

And when I'm trying to use   component i recieve message: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'WithAlertProps': error

So how to inform typescript that it have error value from HOC?

Comment: Just remove ```& WithAlertProps``` from the function return type

Comment: it doesn't change anything. Still the same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misaligned types. Your `withAlert` hoc recieves a component with `P & WithAlertProps` props and returns a component recieving `P` props.

```typescript
const withAlert = <P extends unknown>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P & WithAlertProps>
): React.FC<P> => (props) => {
    return (
        <Component {...props} error={"sample error"} />
    );
};
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3zXw)